# how to update httpd on mac os Catalina

Tags: macos, apache

I am required to update Apache httpd on my mac. Running Catalina 10.16.7 and Apache/2.4.46 (Unix).  This is a security requirement.

If I had Red Hat linux, I could use

```
yum install httpd
```

If I had a debian linux, I could use

```
apt-get upgrade httpd
```

Mac has homebrew, so I tried

```
brew install httpd
```

Unfortunately, homebrew installs a second copy of httpd and leaves the original in place. Not acceptable to security.

I suspect that I need to wait for an Apple update (unfortunately security team will not wait).

Are there other methods to update httpd?  Or, am I forced to upgrade to Big Sur?

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, httpd is upgraded by Apple during standard Mac OSX releases.  I upgraded my Mac to Big Sur: no change in httpd version.

If you need to upgrade httpd on your Mac OSX, then be prepared to waste a lot of time.  No one in this forum had an answer. I could not find one anywhere.  I can only conclude that there is no way to easily do it.  I guess that you could go to the Apache site and compile your own version.

Time to walk away. Sometimes that is the solution.  Problem solved.